# How to make a variable value passage for preprocessor?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

Here I know that the following code simply copies the character `i` rather than its value to the preprocessor statement (which makes a error for undefined symbol `i` in compile-time).

What I want is:

Is their a way such that the compiler treats, `i` as a variable with some value rather than a character ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT(x) printf("%d \n", y ## x)

int main(void) {  
    int y1=0 , y2=1 , y3=4;

    for(int i=1; i <= 3; ++i) {          
        PRINT(i);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: There's surely a duplicate of this question but I can't seem to find it.. anyway you can't run the code with the preprocessor itself: that's pre-compile time phase and it's totally different from runtime phase.

Comment: `PRINT(i);` simply expands to `printf("%d \n", yi);` how should the preprocessor know the runtime values of `i`. It's just simple text processing.

Comment: hmm i tried to search for such question but in vain. so finally i decided to post it. i got this doubt when i came across reading the book "programming in c by kochan" (13th chapter The # Operator and ## operator.) @Marco A.

Comment: why not use an array, and then `PRINT(y[i])` ?

Comment: hmm that's what my intention is... @πάνταῥεῖ i want to know is there a way to treat 'i' as a value rather than a text.

Comment: Pre-processing is done **prior** to compilation. It's operating on the source file to create a "patched" version of it, which then in turn is fed to the compiler. From those dependencies one should conclude that compiler functionalitiy has **nothing** to do with pre-processor actions.

Comment: For your reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Comment: @kay1 _"i want to know is there a way to treat 'i' as a value rather than a text."_ You can say `PRINT(1);`, `PRINT(2);` etc. of course. In a loop over `i` this would need a `switch(i) { case 1: PRINT(1); break; /* ... */ }`. But that's not generic, you need to know the possible _values_ in advance.

Comment: @MarcoA. I'm also almost sure I've seen duplicates for this question by means of wanting to create `y1`, `y2`, `y3` as can be done with an `eval` feature supported by several scripting languages. But I'm not so sure about seeing one, so precisely asking about how to use the preprocessor to achieve this. I've tried to answer it with best of my knowledge.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree with you and you wrote a great answer. +1 by me and next time someone mentions something similar I'll link your answer :)

Comment: @MarcoA. I have found a serious problem with my _"dispatched macro"_ proposal: All of that variables need to be defined [to make my sample work](http://ideone.com/JlX9Zg). Actually I have no idea how to fix this :-( ... If you find a way, feel free _to steal_ it. I've deleted my answer now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ right, although for what the user wanted I believe your code works just fine (http://ideone.com/V9kz35). Except with some template machinery (I don't even want to think about it, there are a million easier and more readable ways) I don't think it could be made generic. Your solution still seems good to me

Comment: @MarcoA. _"Your solution still seems good to me"_ I don't think it's really a solution. The sample only works, if `prefix` and `varid` match all of the declared variables. And yes, agreed: I also don't see a solution, how to make this generic with the preprocessor. The more poor proposal by just using the switch (which is pretty useless in practice), is enough to be mentioned in my comment from above IMHO. Again, feel free to take it to write an answer.

Comment: FYI, I changed my answer to include a solution based on boost preprocessor which might be closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

### About the pre-processor

First of all, I think there's a need to clarify how the preprocessor works: it *pre*-processes the input files, which means it runs before the compiler. Unfortunatly, for historical reasons, it doesn't know anything about C or C++, doesn't parse anything, and just does very simple textual operations on words and parenthesis. Just to illustrate my point:

```
#define this __FILE__
#define file -- Hell no!
#define fine(a, b) fine: a ## _ ## b
Ok, so this is not a valid C or C++ file
But the preprocessor will run just fine(go, try!)
```

Run this with a pre-processor, for example `gcc -x c -E -P test.txt` and you'll get:

```
Ok, so "test.txt" is not a valid C or C++ -- Hell no!
But the preprocessor will run just fine: go_try!
```

So, obviously, when the preprocessor sees `PRINT(i)` in your code, it replaces it with `printf("%d \n", yi)` without thinking much about it. And it has absolutely no idea `i` is a variable, don't even think about evaluating it's value.

### Solutions

Basically, what you want is print a bunch of numbers.

1. You *could* simply do

   ```
   printf("0\n1\n4\n");
   ```

   But this lacks makes changing numbers cumbersome,
2. so let's go with

   ```
   printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", 0, 1, 4);
   ```

   Which makes it easy to change a number, but not to add/remove one.
3. Ok so how about:

   ```
   printf("%d\n", 0);
   printf("%d\n", 1);
   printf("%d\n", 4);
   ```

   Yeah, you can change/add/remove numbers easily but as any sane programmer you hate repetition. So, we need some kind of loop.
4. By far the simplest and most straightforward way to iterate in C is at runtime, using an array:

   ```
   int [] y = { 0, 1, 4 };
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(y)/sizeof(int); ++i) {
       printf("%d\n", y[i]);
   }
   ```
5. If you want, you can hide the `printf` using a function:

   ```
   inline void print_int(int* y, int i) { print_int(y[i]); }
   int [] y = { 0, 1, 4 };
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(y)/4; ++i) print_int(y, i);
   ```
6. And going further with functions:

   ```
   inline void print_int(int x)           { printf("%d\n", x); }
   inline void print_int(int* y, int i)   { print_int(y[i]); }
   inline void print_ints(int * y, int n)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
           print_int(y, i);
   }
   template<int n> // C++
   inline void print_ints(const int[n] & y) { print_ints(&y[0], n); }

   int [] y = { 0, 1, 4 };
   print_ints(y); // C++

   // or in C:
   print_ints(y, sizeof(y)/sizeof(int));
   ```

   Now, what if you absolutely want the generated code to look like solution 3. ? This means you need the iteration to happen at compile-time. Tricky!
7. That's where the preprocessor can come into play. There are (hacky) ways to make it do this kind of things. I *strongly* recommend not implementing this yourself (except to play), but use the `Boost.preprocessor` library instead:

   ```
   #define PRINTER(R,D, NUMBER) printf("%d\n", NUMBER);

   #define NUMBERS (0, 1, 4)
   BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH(PRINTER, _, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_LIST(NUMBERS))
   // will expand to printf("%d\n", 0); printf("%d\n", 1); printf("%d\n", 4);
   ```

Comment: Do you mind adding a short explanation on why your solution works, even if it is apparently self-evident?

Comment: @HugoSFerreira: yeah, I posted that from my phone. Thanks to your comment, I'm afraid I did a bit more than a "short" explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Under standard C, this is not possible; during preprocessing, the compiler simply sees the identifier `i` as simply that - an identifier. It does not know that `i` is of type `int`, or that it's even a variable in the first place.

The easiest way to achieve what's intended is to use an array, like so:

```
int i;
int y[] = { 0, 1, 4 };

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) // NOTE: arrays in C start at index 0, not 1
{
    printf("%d \n", y[i]);
}
```

Also note that I got rid of the macro, as you want to use the *value* of a runtime variable `i` to select another runtime variable.